# ImportError: No module named simple while running manage.py test in django project

Tags: python, django

Traceback:

```
./manage.py test my_app
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/zuber/projects/private-CR/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/zuber/projects/private-CR/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/zuber/projects/private-CR/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 30, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/home/zuber/projects/private-CR/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 381, in run_from_argv
    parser = self.create_parser(argv[0], argv[1])
  File "/home/zuber/projects/private-CR/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in create_parser
    self.add_arguments(parser)
  File "/home/zuber/projects/private-CR/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 52, in add_arguments
    test_runner_class = get_runner(settings, self.test_runner)
  File "/home/zuber/projects/private-CR/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 152, in get_runner
    test_module = __import__(test_module_name, {}, {}, force_str(test_path[-1]))
ImportError: No module named simple
```

I tried to remove **init**.py from app folder and then I've got "No module named app_name". When I removed **init**.py from project folder - console said "No module named settings". How to test my app?

Comment: why did you remove that? What reason?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069880/running-django-tutorial-tests-fail-no-module-named-polls-tests - the only answer where the problem is close to mine

Comment: The difference between your question and that one is that your folders are supposed to be modules, and his were not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the problem by removing

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'django.test.simple.DjangoTestSuiteRunner'
```

from settings.py

see related question [running all tests post django 1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20904979/running-all-tests-post-django-1-6)

Answer (score 3):

So first of all, you need to put your two `__init__.py`s back where you found them. They are what allow you to import things from that module. Secondly, you should post the code in `manage.py` so we have a better idea of what is going on, but it looks to me like you had a line in there that looks something like `import django.contrib.admin.util` or `import <something> from django.contrib.admin.util`. This module was removed in the release of django that you're using, so you should replace any occurrances of `django.contrib.admin.util` with `django.contrib.admin.utils`.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env python
    import os
    import sys

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")

        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

I've found only one django.contrib.admin.util in admin.py and replaced it with utils. But nothing's changed

Comment: What file are you changing? `manage.py` or the file that you're trying to import from? You shouldn't be messing with the django source code unless you konw what you're doing...

Comment: I didn't change django source code. I've just replaced admin.util with admin.utils in admin.py of my application.

Answer (score 0):

For me while using Pycharm the problem was that the PyCharm test runner was not compatible with Django 2.0

The solution was:
replace line 254:EOF with

```
  if VERSION[1] > 1 or VERSION[0] > 1:
    return DjangoTeamcityTestRunner(**options).run_tests(test_labels,
                                                         extra_tests=extra_tests, **options)

  return run_the_old_way(extra_tests, options, test_labels, verbosity)
```

Instead of:

```py
  if VERSION[1] > 1:
    return DjangoTeamcityTestRunner(**options).run_tests(test_labels,
                                                         extra_tests=extra_tests, **options)

  return run_the_old_way(extra_tests, options, test_labels, verbosity)
```